# Full responsive UIView inside a UIScrollView using autolayout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode6

I'm trying to understand how autolayout works under XCode6, but there's a lot of mysterious things that runs away from my mind. Autolayout and constraints philosofy can be very hard to learn, but I realized that life can be easier using these tools...

For your information, I need to build a chat view with a table (the messages) and a view containing a text field (the send message pane) nested in a UIView that is again nested in a UIScrollView, so I can shift up the scroll view as the keyboard appears under the textfield.

I read a lot of tutorials and watched a lot of video until I found the useful tutorial [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/?utm_source=maniacdev-ao&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=uiscrollview-autolayout-ios). There's a Xcode project in Github of what the tutorial explains, too.

In his tutorial, Mike Woelmer tells that

> One of the big pain points with the old way of setting up a
>   UIScrollView was communicating the content size to the scroll view. It
>   was fairly straightforward to calculate your content size if the
>   content in the UIScrollView was an image. But it was not as easy if
>   your scroll view included a mixed bag of buttons, labels, custom
>   views, and text fields. Lengthy code adjustments were needed to
>   reflect constant changes in device rotations and phone size
>   differences.

So Mike explains the way to adapt the UIView, using placeholder and forcing the view inside the scrollview to fits the device's screen, creating in viewDidLoad some NSLayoutConstraint:

> The solution is to look outside the scroll view and attach a
>   constraint to the view controller’s main view. This cannot be done in
>   interface builder, so we will have to write some code. Interface
>   builder is still complaining, though, so we have to add a placeholder
>   width constraint to make it happy.

I tried to use parts of the code of the tutorial for my project, but I cannot get a working view controller for my needs (I always get errors). **Which is the best approach to do this? Am I on the right road?**

[image]

Last but not least, I'm italian, so pardon for my english. If something is not clear enough, please leave me a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to set both alignment and size constraints in order for Autolayout to take care of the rest for you.  If you don't provide enough information you get warning.  If you provide conflicting information you get errors.

You need basically to provide enough information for Autolayout to calculate the UIView frame property (i.e., x-position, y-position, width, height).

For example, by providing the distance constraints from the top, right, bottom, and left edges, Autolayout has enough information to draw that UIView's frame rectangle.  But you could also provide just the distance constraints from the top and left edges and then provide a size and height constraint.

You can also configure the key constraints you need and then click 'resolve auto layout issues' and choose 'add missing constraints' though sometimes it doesn't give you what you want.  It is better to understand that how Autolayout accomplishes what I described above.

If you mess up, it's usually easier to clear all the constraints and start over.  Do it a few times and you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you, just now I'm trying to accomplish this task, but sometimes I get very frustrated about it.

Comment: if you have a specific question about my answer just ask away!

Comment: BelievesInSanta, I am grateful to you because at least you answered me, and your answer is clear and exhaustive. I did not want to be argumentative with you, but with whom downvoted me without first asking, for example, to add some more information.

Comment: Welcome to SO, buddy :)